# implement an updates from mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Im developing a client-server real-time program and I need my server to be up-to-date always. Unill now I have been implement a GET request from the server every X seconds that returns all the entities from the MongoDB.
Now I have big amount of entities and I need to GET only the entities which have been updated since the last GET request.
I think about running sequence in the db for each entity and check every X seconds if the sequens have been increased.
But I will prefer a better way.
Is there any way to get only the recent changes from mongo?  Or any nicer architecture ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a last updated time in the collection. In the client side, you can maintain a last get time.

In the subsequent requests, get all the documents from collection where last updated time is greater than last get time. This way you will get the documents that got updated or inserted since you last get the data (I.e. delta).

Edit:

MongoDB maintains the date object in UTC format. As long as the date at client side is maintained in UTC and send the same data in the subsequent request, it should retrieve the latest updated records.

Comment: Yes its possible, we have a last update time. But the problem is what happens when we change the time to summer-time, winter-time ?